# How can I get this number, from a string, and be able to use it in math operations?

Tags: java

I have the number '19,476.86' in a text file and I would like to use it to perform math operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, how do I do it?

```java
        String s = "19.476,90";
        DecimalFormat  formateador = new DecimalFormat ("#.00");
        Number resultado = formateador.parse(s);
        System.out.println("Resultado: " + resultado);
```

Output:

```
Resultado: 19.476
```

I want to use the full number and not have the ',80' left out

Comment: Could it be because you have your decimal point and comma switched around?

Comment: "I have the number '19,476.86' in a text file" - that's not what your code shows. What's *actually* in the file?

Comment: @JonSkeet about the txt file is a simply string what have that number

Comment: @CalvinP. i from Argentina...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Is the content of the text file "19,476.86" or "19.476,90"? You've described one, and then given a different one in your source code. It's very hard to help with contradictory requirements. (And chances are the duplicate actually contains the answer...)